# html form and php post not working, information is being rewritten

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, forms

I have the following code that generates my form on my html page

```
<input type="hidden" name="name[<? echo $productid; ?>]" value="<? echo     $rows["id"];?>">

                <select name="name<? echo $rows["id"];  ?>" >

                <?
                for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($_SESSION['people']['name']); $i++){
                echo "<option>";
                echo $_SESSION['people']['name'][$i];
                echo "</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
```

then, this form is submited to a page that is currently holding

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and its printing out the following

```
array(3) { 
    ["name"]=> array(2) { 
        [2]=> string(1) "2" 
        [6]=> string(1) "6" 
    } 
    ["name2"]=> string(12) "first person" 
    ["name6"]=> string(15) "andother person" 
}
```

However, as you can see, both names are being posted properly, however they are not properly associated.

string(1) is pointing to both 6 and 2. these are my product numbers and they need to be paired with a name.

can you please let me know how i can cleanup my form and properly with a a foreach loop, extract each attribute. ie the name, and the id number ( 6, 2 ...)

basically, i wanna know which name is being associated with which product id number => 2, 6, etc...
i want the name to be save as $name and the id as $id.
then insert to table (name, id) values ( $name, $id)...
however, it should be in a loop to grab all of the $names and $ids.
so the first run through, it should grab "first Person and group it with 2"
2nd run through, it should grab "another person and group it with 6"

Sorry, english is not my first language. Please excuse any poor grammer.

Comment: string(1) is simply referring to the type and length of the strings. "2" and "6" are both strings that are one character long, so they will both have string(1) associated with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string(1)` bit is telling you the type of variable and length, not the key. If your arrays are related the way it looks like, you can get the info with

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $id) {
    echo $_POST['name' . $id];
}
```

If you plan on using any of this info with your SQL calls, be sure to sanitize the input first or you will be susceptible to SQL Injections.

**Edit:**
If you are trying to construct an id => name type array, you could do this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($_POST['name'] as $id) {
    $arr[$id] = $_POST['name' . $id];
}
print_r($arr);
//should print an array like ('2' => 'first person', '6' => 'another person')
```

Comment: Thats worked great for the name portion. Im also passing a id number. How can I have that printed out. its currently printing out first person
andother person without what item they used ($productid)

Comment: Is it not the `$id` that I have in the loop?

Comment: well you have name as id, and thats printing out the name. the id is this portion.
    ["name"]=> array(2) { 
        [2]=> string(1) "2" 
        [6]=> string(1) "6" }

Comment: so, for each name that prints out, I want the product number that it was associated with as well.

Comment: This is going through the array that is assigned to the post variable `name`, which is based off of your form. It appeared that each element in `$_POST['name']` was an ID, so that's how I used it. I've update the answer to (maybe) get you a little further

Answer (score 0):

`String(1)` means a string with one character. The result seems fine to me. Never use `sizeof()` -function in loops. It's faster to assign array-size to a var, as calling this function every loop.

or use

```
$sOptions = '';
foreach($_SESSION['people']['name'] AS $i => $sName) {
    $sOptions .= '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$sName.'</option>';
}
print '<select name="name'.$rows["id"].'">'.$sOptions.'</select>';
```

Edit:
If you give the the id ($i) to options values, you will receive the selected id on post